# Include .jsp page inside another dynamically according to url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm using Java with Servlets and JSP to create a basic application.

I have this basic html file I call the base layout, which has the basic page structure, with the navigation menus, header and footer.

I also have a `register.jsp` page, in which the user can register.

How can I include that `register.jsp` into the base layout when the user hits the `/register` url?

Currently, I dump the html content of the register page from the Servlet using the `PrintWriter` object and use ajax to render the content on the base page dynamically. But this is really a bad practice.

Comment: Why not use an iframe inside the HTML to display the JSP, or write the HTML in a modular way which will allow you to re-use it inside the JSP (e.g. header, body, footer etc)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know. How can I do that modular way you are talking about? The iframe sounds a bit wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed that is bad practice.

The simpler choice that can be done easily is to convert your html file to a jsp. Then within the jsp you can include any other resource you want. Consider this example:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <jsp:include  flush="true" page="/templates/css.jsp"/>
        <jsp:include  flush="true" page="/templates/scripts.jsp"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <jsp:include  flush="true" page="/templates/header.jsp"/>
                <jsp:include  flush="true" page="/templates/top_menu_visitor.jsp"/>
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <jsp:include  flush="true" page="/templates/top_content_visitors.jsp"/>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <jsp:include  flush="true" page="/templates/footer_credits.jsp"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example you have a template page that includes many components, most of wich are common between different pages. This can be very well be your index.jsp. For the register jsp you just have to create a new jsp page like this and just change a couple of section.

This is one way to go. In Java EE, there are many frameworks that can automate this process.

Comment: Good answer, working well with Spring MVC and custom views location.  Kinda surprising this is not a more viewed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<jsp:include>` combined with `<c:if>` conditional block that checks  current URL.

Current request URL can be obtained using `${pageContext.request.requestURI}`

There's also [Apache Tiles library](http://tile.apache.org) that help overcome lack of reusability on JSP

See more about `<jsp:include>` on Java EE5 tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html

Comment: The thing is what defines my URL's are Servlet mappings. So the RegistrationServlet is mapped to a `register.html` route, which simply prints a html form. If I access the `register.html` url directly, I don't see the base layout. What I currently do is dynamically call that url using ajax.

Comment: You can also check the request URL on the servlet using `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` method and perform the redirection accordingly. This however is considered outdated practice. Consider re-structuring your application into MVC (Model View Controller) pattern

Comment: Any links to explain the MVC pattern using Servlets and JSP?

Comment: There are few popular libraries to help you implement MVC, I recommend Spring MVC to start with. Also consider JSF.